# How to pass variable from git HEAD (azure devops)

Tags: bash, docker, azure-devops, devops

I ran these code inside bash script task on azure devops

> ```
>     containerVersion = "(git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD)"
>     $(containerVersion)
> ```

I got "231bae9" which is the 7 commit ID. I want to pass this value to docker pull command

> docker pull xx.azurecr.io/xx/xx:$(containerVersion)

but I got syntax error, help please ... thanks a lot

Comment: `docker pull xx.azurecr.io/xx/xx:"$containerVersion"` ?

Comment: @NullDev have tried that, 
got this "xx.azurecr.io/xx/xx:git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD"

Comment: Your bash syntax is wrong: you want `containerVersion="$(git ...)"`, not `containerVersion="(git ...)"`. Note the dollar sign. After that, see @NullDev's reply. I recommend *not* using `--short` here though: always use the full hash ID in scripts.

Comment: Is `docker pull` command in the same script? I think in this case the right syntax would be  `docker pull xx.azurecr.io/xx/xx:$containerVersion`. Have you tried that?

Comment: got worse result "containerVersion: command not found" ... anyway i've solved it by "xx.azurecr.io/xx/xx:${BUILD_SOURCEVERSION:0:7}" thanks